# How to connect Cassandra Database to Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, cassandra

I am trying to connect my **Cassandra database** to **Eclipse**. I was created a table in Cassandra using Terminal. Now I want to get that table contents to the **Eclipse console terminal**. How to connect my Cassandra database to Eclipse. I am using the Ubuntu system. Please help me.

Comment: Can you clarify what your end goal is? Are you looking to create an application that works with Cassandra data? What have you tried so far? Are you seeing any errors? You might want to start with the [Cassandra Client Drivers](http://www.planetcassandra.org/apache-cassandra-client-drivers/).

Comment: @JerodJohnson Actually I am new in Cassandra and Eclipse. And I want to know, how to connect with Cassandra and get the table contents to a page.

Answer (score 2):

You can go with setup using following steps:

First go to market place and add **DBeaver** Plugin in you Eclipse

**Now Connect your cassandra Database:**
Create a JDBC Data Source for Cassandra Data

Follow the steps below to load the driver JAR in DBeaver.

**Setup Driver Manager:**

1. Open the DBeaver application and, in the Databases menu, select the Driver Manager option. Click New to open the Create New Driver form.
2. In the Driver Name box, give your Database name or any preffered name.
3. Download cassandra-jdbc jar
4. To add Driver jar, click Add File.and path to cassandra-jdbc jar
5. Click the Find Class button and select the CassandraDriver class from the results. This will automatically fill the Class Name field at the top of the form.
6. Add jdbc:cassandra: in the URL Template field.

**Create New Connection**

1.Click new Connection link and select recently created cassandra driver among the available drivers.

2.Provide JDBC url,username and password.

3.Click test connection

For Detailed Reference  https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/cassandra-jdbc-dbvr.rst

Best of Luck!!!!

Comment: @ Melbin Mathai, Did my post  help to you?

Comment: DBeaver latest version does not support cassandra anymore.